# Segmentation fault std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, vector, tcp

I write a function to return a vector and call it in other functions, in some function, it runs well, but in some, it throws the Segmentation fault.
This is my functionA, it returns a vector

```
std::vector<std::string> functionA(std::vector<std::string>  l){
    ...

        char *list_inorder;
        int nnn = sprintf(list_inorder,"%-5d%-35s%-20s%-8s\n",(i),(s.at(1)).c_str(),(s.at(2)).c_str(), (s.at(0)).c_str());
        ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how I call it in other function, I use the same method to call it but some can work some cannot.

```
std::vector<std::string> vectorA=functionA(vectorB);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `tcp`? There is nothing in the question related to TCP at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never point `list_inorder` to anything before you `sprintf` to it.

That means undefined behavior. Intermittent crashes are expected from undefined behavior.

Since you are using streams everywhere else, why not a stream for the output instead of sprintf? from memory `ostringstream`, but google will give a better answer than my memory...

A simple fix would be to change `char *list_inorder;` to `char list_inorder[50];` (assumes 50 chars is enough to fit your string) - this is not ideal and using streams would be better.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I want to save some char* in a format so I use sprintf, I am not familiar with C++, what does it mean "point list_inorder to anything"?

Comment: If you are not familiar with C++ then read a book or do an online course before trying to write in it! `list_inorder` is a pointer. You have not set it's value so it is not pointing to anything and cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you, I use a char list_inorder[256]; ant it works, Thank you!